# libjpeg.8.dylib reference broken after brew upgrade

Tags: xetex, miktex, mac

After trying to fix a hyphenation problem in various ways, I can't compile any Tex documents anymore, even after uninstalling and reinstalling Miktex.
The error message I get when I try is as follows:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib 
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/xelatex Reason: image not found

Error: Command crashed: xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode 
"Thesis-Firstname-Lastname".tex
```

Sadly, I do not know what exactly broke this reference. Using Luatex as compiler doesn't help either.

I'm relatively new to Latex, so I don't quite understand the error message. I already tried reinstalling libjpeg, but nothing is changed. 
I use Miktex for Mac.
I'd be glad about any recommendations to fix this or understand what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: Why don't you install texlive/mactex (http://www.tug.org/mactex/)? As the download page for miktex for mac write: "Please beware that MiKTeX for Mac is still in an experimental stage.", so it is not something for someone who is new to latex.

Comment: you might be right. I am using a template created by a friend who works on win10 using Miktex, which is why I wanted to try running Miktex for Mac first. As I currently still can't find the reason for the problems I have (I also never was able to run the package manager), I might just try MacTex instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to MacTex over MikTex solves my problems for now. I can even continue to use the same template, I thought there might be a problem with Xelatex or similar if I switch, but it runs for now. Thanks to Ulrike Fischer!